# Find the string occurence and wrap it with a span

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, dom

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>if(true)<span class="openParen bm1">{</span></div>
  <div>cout<<"hey";cin>>x;</div>
  <div><span class="closeParen bm1>}</span></div>
</div>
```

I wanted to find `cout` using regex, something like `/cout[^;]*;/` and then wrap it with a `span`.

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div>if(true)<span class="openParen bm1">{</span></div>
  <div><span id="group">cout<<"hey";</span>cin>>x;</div>
  <div><span class="closeParen bm1>}</span></div>
</div>
```

How will i find the regex occurence and the wrap it with a span? Anyone please?

**UPDATE:** I inserted `cin>>x;` after `cout`, cin shouldn't be wrapped.

I want to use something like this

```
text.replace(/(cout[^;]*;)/g, '<span class="group">$1</span>');
```

But i dont know how to apply it in DOM. anyone?

**BUG** for cin>> and cout<<, they cant be wrap until ; http://jsfiddle.net/3N4AE/11/

Comment: are you building the markup or are you getting it from some place and outputting it as is? because it seems it's somehow getting parsed for the parenthesis, can't you do the same for `cout`?

Comment: Can't do the same for cout. This is actually a text editor with tracing capaility using contenteditable div, i just want to group cout until ; for presentation of step by step by process of the code. something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you would apply the regex to your DOM using jQuery:

```
$('#wrapper div').filter(':contains("cout")').each(function () {
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/(cout[^;]*;)/g, '<span class="group">$1</span>'));
});
```

**[Demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/3N4AE/5/)**

Comment: i think you can remove filter of cout?

Comment: @extraRice It would work without the filter but then the regex would be applied to all the `<div>` elements, not sure how much of a performance hit that would mean for your application

Comment: i think we are having problem with '<<' the only that is being wrapped is 'cout'

Comment: @extraRice you want to wrap `cin` also? or any statement separated by `;`?

Comment: This answer is not causing me any bugs but it doesnt wrap the entire cout<<"something";... a problem with << maybe, you can help @tushargupta

Comment: @extraRice works fine in the fiddle doesn't it? can you update the fiddle with the actual text that's giving you trouble?

Comment: @extraRice you should use `elem.text()` as the base for the regex match, not the `html()` since the html contains the tags encoded as `&lt;` http://jsfiddle.net/koala_dev/3N4AE/12/

Comment: i'd used .html() because using elem.text() removes the br. it works fine but when text is something like cout<<one<<two; same problem goes again: here my regex: text = text.replace(/(cout\s*(&lt;&lt;[^;]*)+;)/g, '<span class="group">$1</span>');

Comment: @extraRice the problem is that this `cout<<one<<two;` is not valid HTML markup, the browser will try to use `<one` as a new HTML tag, you should encode the output beforehand so it renders properly with html entities

Comment: @koala_dev: What do you mean i should encode the output before hand?

Comment: @extraRice never mind, I no longer think that's an issue, try using this regex instead `/(cout\s*(&lt;&lt;[^;&]*)+;)/g`

Comment: @koala_dev, not wrapping cout having more than one whitespace like cout<<"  two space before  ";

Answer (score 1):

update Regex way
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3N4AE/6/)

```
$('#wrapper div').filter(':contains("cout")').each(function () {
    var x = $(this);
    var txt = x.text();
    x.html(txt.replace(/(cout[^;]*;)/g, '<span class="group">$1</span>'));
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3N4AE/)

```
var x =$('#wrapper div').filter(':contains("cout")');
var txt = x.text();
x.text('').append('<span id="group">'+txt+'</span>');
```

updated after OP updated question

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3N4AE/2/)

```
var x = $('#wrapper div').filter(':contains("cout")');
var txt = x.text();
x.text('');
var cout = txt.split(';');
$.each(cout, function (i, val) {
    if (val.indexOf('cout') > -1) {
        x.append('<span class="group">' + val + ';</span>');
    } else {
        x.append(val + ';');
    }
});
```

update

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3N4AE/3/)

```
$('#wrapper div').filter(':contains("cout")').each(function () {
    var x = $(this);
    var txt = x.text();
    x.text('');
    var cout = txt.split(';');
    $.each(cout, function (i, val) {
        if (val.indexOf('cout') > -1) {
            x.append('<span class="group">' + val + ';</span>');
        } else {
            x.append(val + ';');
        }
    });
});
```

updated after [koala-dev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2049063/koala-dev) comment

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/3N4AE/4/)

```
$('#wrapper div').filter(':contains("cout")').each(function () {
    var x = $(this);
    var txt = x.text();
    x.text('');
    var cout = txt.split(';');
    $.each(cout, function (i, val) {
        if (val.indexOf('cout') > -1) {
            x.append('<span class="group">' + val + ';</span>');
        } else if ($.trim(val) != '') {
            x.append(val + ';');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: The question is that he wants to use `regex`.

Comment: @extraRice Note that this is appending an extra `;` at the end of the text

Comment: @koala_dev: yes, it cause me some trouble. I have a suggestion in my question.

Answer (score -2):

This should help

```
var pattern = /cout[^;]*;/;

var txt = $('#wrapper').find('div:nth-child(2)').text();
var el = $('#wrapper').find('div:nth-child(2)');

$(el).text("").append('<span id="group">' + txt + '</span');
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghXGC/)

Comment: you're not even using the pattern, also there's no need to use `find()` or to have two variables or to clear the text when you can use `html()`, finally I think it's pretty obvious that OP won't always find the pattern in the second div